# Jeep Grande Cherokee clicking when warm

Tags: jeep, noise, grand-cherokee

A Jeep Grande Cherokee 1998 runs perfectly fine for about 6 miles (Or 15 minutes), and then starts to slowly at first, and more frequently later, have a behavior where it sounds like a high frequency to lower frequency sound lasting about 3 seconds, followed by a click, followed by 10 seconds of normal behavior, and a repeat. It seems to stop doing this after 3-4 times, then repeat after a minute of normal behavior. It also seems to improve slightly when stopped at a stoplight or other similar thing. When the click happens, there is a dragging to the left. The car is drivable, but it is more difficult.

What is going on with the vehicle, and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: Does the vehicle have ABS? Can you stop and listen for where the noise is coming from when it happens?

Comment: It only happens when the car is actually moving. I'm pretty sure it has ABS.

Comment: Is this problem still occuring?

Comment: @Sly: Funny you should ask, we just got it fixed today... Will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem that was going on was that the alignment was off. I'm not entirely sure why it didn't happen to begin with, but after fixing the alignment (And replacing the tires), the problem went away completely.